# Windows thinks my Python path is from the app store

Tags: python, windows, bash, path

Windows 10 thinks my Python path is:

`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`

Even if I install it from the store, this path does not allow me permission in `bash`.

When it is:

`C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`

How do I change this? I have set the path in system environment but Windows!

Comment: have you tried `python3.7` as a command

Comment: Yes! INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: FYI, the permission error with appexec aliases is a bug in bash, from Cygwin and friends. They haven't updated their code to support appexec aliases, which are unhandled reparse points (i.e. most operations on them immediately fail) that should normally be passed to `CreateProcessW` without trying to inspect the file. To actually inspect the file, you'd have to open and read the reparse point, and parse the undocumented format of an appexec alias to get the target path.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so by turning the App installer off in App execution aliases. It has fixed the access denied problem

[App Execution Aliases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPkI2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by removing it automatically on the **settings** page, Under **Apps and Features**, there are **application execution aliases**.

[image]